# 301 redirect of static page

Tags: seo

If I want to 301 redirect (SEO required) from old static pages to new static pages, what should I do?

I search in Google and find that it seems cannot be set inside the static page (meta tag) for 301 redirect.

My server is Netscape Enterprise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a list of how to do it in several different environments, [how-to-redirect-a-webpage](http://www.webconfs.com/how-to-redirect-a-webpage.php). Unfortunately not Netscape Enterprise, but maybe it could give you a clue. It does go through how to redirect a html file.

This link may help as well, [Search Engines and 301 Permanent Redirects](http://blogs.oracle.com/elving/entry/301_permanent_redirects) it mentions Netscape Enterprise Server, but only in saying that its not possible to do a 301 redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct in that you can't have a static page respond with a 301 permanent redirection.

You need to use some serverside technology to set the response headers, e.g. JSP:

```
<%
response.setStatus(301);
response.setHeader( "Location", "http://www.newpage.com" );
response.setHeader( "Connection", "close" );
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Netscape Enterprise, but on most web-servers (at least in IIS) you can set up redirects (both 301 and 302) for static files within the web-server admin area, i.e. not within the file itself. I imagine Netscape Enterprise would offer a similar function.